# Internal server error after import sql dump in phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, apache-2.2

I have a problem with import of 20mb sql dumo by using phpMyAdmin 3.4.1 . As you can see [here](http://hosting-rus.ru/mysql/phpMyAdmin341/testtest.php) there are big values for max scipt's execution time. In apache log I see the following:

```
[Thu Jul 14 16:28:37 2011] [error] [client 195.64.203.162] Premature end of script headers: php, referer: http://hosting-rus.ru/mysql/phpMyAdmin341/db_import.php?db=jbs3&server=1&token=141da7abe59b0f8f53b3ce32fd6f9ead
[Thu Jul 14 16:28:37 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 195.64.203.162] Zlib: Compressed 624 to 377 : URL /php-bin/php/mysql/phpMyAdmin341/import.php, referer: http://hosting-rus.ru/mysql/phpMyAdmin341/db_import.php?db=jbs3&server=1&token=141da7abe59b0f8f53b3ce32fd6f9ead
```

And now I have no ideas how to fix this 500 error while import sql dump. Could you help me? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

use tools like [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) for large SQL dumps.

This allows you to either upload the file on the page or upload it to the server and load it from there. 
Bigdump will cut the sql file in pieces and insert it bit by bit.

Comment: It's not a good way. On my another server I can upload dumps with size about 40mb and no problems. But here I resolve an internal server error (and 502 bad gateway sometimes). I also can upload dump by using a shell. But the errors described above make me worry about a server:)

Comment: its probably just the settings in php.ini (max filesize) that are working against u, also uploading big files can cause timeouts on the webserver.